How to export a Matplotlib figure to PDF-1.3?
When saving a plot as a PDF, Matplotlib generates files based on the PDF 1.4 standard. (You can check the PDF version by opening the file in a text editor).
However, I run into problems with such PDFs when I use them in Microsoft PowerPoint and other MS Office tools, and then export the MS document again into a PDF. Most notably, I lose areas with transparent colors that turn completely white. Obviously the Microsoft PDF engine seems to be the bottleneck (so far I have not found a way to change the Microsoft PDF engine).
I can reproduce the problem on a recent MacOS with the below code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar([1, 2, 3], [224, 620, 425], 
       facecolor=(0.3,0.7,0.9,0.3), 
       ec='k')
plt.savefig("test.pdf")



I found out that I can fix the problem by converting the PDF to version PDF-1.3. I can do this with Adobe Illustrator by selecting the PDF/X-1a or PDF/X-3 standard in the export settings.
My questions:

How to enforce the PDF-1.3 format in Matplotlib?
How to recover from this transparency problem?

I have tried to save the image as SVG. However, I am encountering similar problems with transparency being lost in some situations. EPS does not support transparent face colors. Also, I don't want to export the image to a rasterized format.

Have you tried selective rasterization?

It is when we convert some elements of the plot into a raster while the rest remains untouched, add rasterized=True to the bar function call

No rasterization, please. My use case requires vector graphics.

According to this discussion on the Adobe forums (which I would take as a credible source), there was no transparency support in PDF 1.3. So there might be a fundamental problem with your attempt.

As noted above apparently PDF1.3 will not allow transparency - eg alpha!=1.  Use facecolor=(0.3,0.7,0.9,1.0) or any other color where the fourth element is 1.0 eg alpha =1.  See https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colors.html for how to specify colors in matplotlib.

@simon Thank you for pointing this out. There's also this summary on Wikipedia.

From the documentation, matplotlib.pyplot.savefig takes a transparency and backend argument that may help you. Also, it takes a format argument so that you could save the figure as png to see if that works instead, if that's an option for you. You could try calling it like this:
plt.savefig("test.png", format="png")


Hello, thank you very much for your answer. As I pointed out in my post, I don't want to have a rasterized image. I also don't think it makes sense to disguise a PNG as a PDF...

I tested to disable/enable transparent background, but it does not solve my problem.

png is a raster format, that's true. perhaps try plt.savefig("test.svg", format="svg") or plt.savefig("test.pdf", backend="pgf").

Neither PGF nor the Cairo backends work. I assume they also use a PDF version >1.3

I am not sure if this is feasible in your actual use case, but one idea would be trying to avoid transparency altogether, by converting your RGBA colors to RGB colors, taking the background color into account (I guess this is sometimes called "flattening"). Given your example, this could look as follows:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rgb_from(rgba, background=(1., 1., 1.)):
    assert len(rgba) == 4 and len(background) == 3
    rgb, a = rgba[:3], rgba[3]
    return tuple(val * a + bg * (1. - a) for val, bg in zip(rgb, background))

_, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar([1, 2, 3], [224, 620, 425], 
       facecolor=rgb_from(rgba=(0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 0.3)), 
       ec='k')
plt.savefig("test.pdf")


This assumes a white background (background=(1., 1., 1.)) and converts your RGBA facecolor to RGB accordingly. The output will look exactly the same as the plot you show on the left. Unfortunately, I could not test how it will behave in PowerPoint, as my Office version apparently does not support PDF images.
